# Selecting/highlighting specific lines in a text - gedit

Tags: text-editors, text-editing, gedit

I'd like to select only specific lines in a gedit file; for example, if the text is composed by 4 lines, I may be able to select only the first one and the last one in order to copy only them.

How could I reach this result?

Answer (score 0):

However in gedit you cant do this. Bit using this simple command in bash you can get 1th and 4th line as you wanted:

```
sed -n -e 1p -e 4p file.txt
```

Will print the lines before 'p' sed command.

Comment: Hello @Wasif_Hasan thank you a lot for your reply. I hope to find an add-on for gedit which allows me to select specific lines in a faster way.

Comment: But I think sed way is faster. Quickly you can get the lines and copy and paste them

Answer (score 0):

In gedit you cannot do multi-selections. You can do it in [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/), it has [mouse shortcuts for multi-selections](https://wiki.freepascal.org/CudaText#Mouse_shortcuts).